# how to add mod expire condition in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

How to add mode expire condition in htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that you have the `mod_expires` module enabled, and then use the following:

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
```

You can add expires times based upon content type as well, see the Apache docs for more info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean mod_expire.

Yes you can add these directives to .htaccess. So long as you have AllowOverride set

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html